# Launch specific method from argument/parameter in Java

Tags: java, android

I would like to launch a specific method from an argument/parameter of another method in Java.

Consider following code:

```
void getResponse(String getUrl, final Activity activity) throws IOException {

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(getUrl)
            .build();

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            call.cancel();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {

            final String myResponse = response.body().string();

            activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(myResponse);
                        //txtString.setText("First Name: "+json.getJSONObject("data").getString("first_name") + "\nLast Name: " + json.getJSONObject("data").getString("last_name"));
                        ReturnedString(json.toString());
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

The public void run() launches ReturnedString(json.toString());
But I would like to be "ReturnedString" a parameter of the getResponse method, so I can reuse getResponse. 
This would mean that getResponse becomes something like:

```
void getResponse(String getUrl, final Activity activity, Method method) throws IOException {
```

And

```
method(json.toString());
```

But it seems not to be working this way.

Albert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  java.util.function.Consumer as an parameter of the method.

```
void getResponse(String getUrl, final Activity activity, final Consumer<String> consumer) throws IOException {

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(getUrl)
            .build();

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            call.cancel();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {

            final String myResponse = response.body().string();

            activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(myResponse);
                        //txtString.setText("First Name: "+json.getJSONObject("data").getString("first_name") + "\nLast Name: " + json.getJSONObject("data").getString("last_name"));
                        //ReturnedString(json.toString());
                        consumer.accept(json.toString());

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

and the call of this method would be:

```
  getResponse(url, activity, new Consumer<String>(){
            @Override
            public void accept(String s) {
                ReturnedString(s);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thank you, Nonika. Android Studio wanted me to make Consumer<String> consumer final, but that seems not to be the biggest problem. But "consumer.apply(json.toString());" seems not to be working, it does not recognize "apply". Do I need to implement a function in the Gradle script to make that work?

Comment: check that you are using  java.util.function.Consumer into your import https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/function/Consumer

Comment: Thanks again. The document you referred to does not contain the apply-function. But as I wrote in another comment; I'd better get to bed - it's past 10 PM here in Denmark ;)

Comment: Sorry you are right it should be accept not apply. its past 1 am here in Georgia :)

Comment: Funny, now I am awake again, I can see why it should be accept, and how I could change it to become apply in stead ;) It helps sleeping.
It's working perfectly now. Thank you so very much! I love this community!

Comment: @Kairos if you slept well, can you now accept the answer? :)

Comment: Done - had just to find out how to accept :) Thanks for your answer and comments

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Function<String, Void>` as third parameter:

Initialize it as follows:

```
import androidx.arch.core.util.Function;

Function<String, Void> function = new Function<String, Void>() {
    @Override
    public Void apply(String input) {
         ReturnedString(input);
    }
}
```

Your method with the `Function` parameter:

```
void getResponse(String getUrl, final Activity activity, final Function<String, Void> function) throws IOException {

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(getUrl)
            .build();

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            call.cancel();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {

            final String myResponse = response.body().string();

            activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(myResponse);
                        function.apply(json.toString());
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Let's assume you need another `Function`, say

```
Function<String, Void> otherFunction = new Function<String, Void>() {
    @Override
    public Void apply(String input) {
         Log.i("TEST", input);
    }
}
```

Then you can use the two `Function`s as follows:

```
for(String day: daysOfWeek){
    if(itIsTuesday(day)){
        getResponse(urlString, activity, function);
    }
    else{
        getResponse(urlString, activity, otherFunction);
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this always use the ReturnedString method? Or am I missing something (which easily could be, I am not that experienced in Java, mildly said.

Comment: @Kairos - if you want it to use another method you need to declare another Function which will use the desired method and pass this into getResponse(String, Activity, Function) instead of the previous Function

Comment: But that would mean that I have to declare new Functions each time I want to use getResponse. In that case, I could write the code directly into the runnable within the getResponse void. I would like to have one getResponse void, and have that void to launch/run a method of my choice in that specific case.

Comment: @Kairos - you would declare all the Functions you want to use with getResponse() once (ideally). You can use getResponse() as often as is required, and you can pass in the specific Function which is suited best to the current situation each time.

Comment: Thank you very much.
I guess I need to go to sleep, since I simply do not see how this works. But I am sure you are right :)

Comment: @Kairos - Me too ;)... I added a code snippet to show what I mean - hope this helps

Comment: While laying in bed, I reviewed your solution in my mind, and think I understood how to make it work. However, the solution Nonika came up with (very similar to yours, by the way - also uses Lambda) has been implemented and works flawlessly Thank you very much for your input, I will keep your solution in mind, you'll never know if it comes be handy later.

Comment: @Kairos - you are right, the two solutions are very similar. However,`java.util.function.Consumer<T>` is only available to devices running Api level 24+ whereas `androidx.arch.core.util.Function<I, O>` can be used with all devices. Since I am currently developing for devices running Android 22+, I'm better off with the `androidx.arch.core.util` package. Which also has a [Consumer](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/util/Consumer). So I guess the best solution is a merger of both answers ;-)

Comment: That sounds interesting! Thanks for that comment. If it turns out, that 24+ is too high, I will consider to merge. But for now: if it works, don't fix it. I'll keep it in mind!!!